# How could this happen? about hibernate and spring and SessionFactory

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a bean in spring's config, which is

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```

and in my MVC controller, I use:

```
@autowired
SessionFactory sf;
```

and spring can inject hibernate's SessionFactory (not just the bean:LocalSessionFactoryBean)

how could this happen, SessionFactory is just a property of `LocalSessionFactoryBean`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll notice `LocalSessionFactoryBean` implements [`FactoryBean<SessionFactory>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html). This interface is used by Spring to create other types of beans. In this case a `SessionFactory`.

In simple terms, Spring will call `getObject()` on the instance of `LocalSessionFactoryBean` which will return the `SessionFactory` instance. To illustrate what goes on, take the Java config way of declaring beans.

```
@Bean 
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() throws IOException {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
    sessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

    return sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

You could also have returned a `LocalSessionFactoryBean` instance and Spring still would have called the `getObject()` method and populated its context with a `SessionFactory` instance.

There are tons of such `FactoryBean` implementations that are useful to Spring developers.

Answer (score 2):

A FactoryBean is a factory for a given Spring bean type. When Spring injects a `Foo`, if it finds a bean of type `FactoryBean<Foo>` in its list of beans, then it will ask this factory to create a `Foo`, and inject this `Foo`. This allows delaying the bean creation until necessary, and customizing its creation (for example, when creating a bean is a complex process, or needs a custom scope).

Read [the javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) and [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-extension-factorybean) for more details.